# Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, namespace

Gostaria de saber o que causou este problema que resolvi "meio que sem saber como".

Criei o arquivo `mysql.php` usando o editor PSPad para debugar algumas queryes e, misteriosamente, começou a parecer o erro:

```
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in C:\localhost\teste\libraries\teste\mysql.php on line 2
```

Sendo que no código não há nada que denote tal erro:

```
<?php
namespace MysqlTESTE;  //utilização de namespaces (CRUD)

include 'server.php'; 
use Mysqli; 
...
```

Resolvi o problema criando um novo arquivo `mysql.php` no Notepad e colando nele o código copiado do arquivo criado no PSPad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eu já passei por isso, a solução é simples, mas até encontrar ela...
É o seguinte:

Alguns editores de texto em ambientes UTF-8 adicionam o BOM no começo dos arquivos de texto.

No seu caso bastaria alterar para o editor usar UTF-8(Sem BOM), caso ele lhe desse essa opção. No Notepad++ por exemplo, você encontra essa e outras opções, no menu "Formatar".

Mas o que é o "BOM"?

A marca de ordem de byte (BOM) é um caractere Unicode usado para denotar a extremidade (ordem de bytes) de um arquivo de texto ou fluxo de dados, com código U+FEFF. Seu uso é opcional e, se usado, deve aparecer no começo do fluxo de texto.

(https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_ordem_de_byte)

Lembro que se eu abrisse o arquivo no netbeans, conseguia ver o caracter ï»¿ no começo da folha

Comment: Realmente eu só consegui resolver esse problema trocando de editor .. no caso usei o "Bloco de Notas" do Windos.  Mas na época fiquei sem entender o que causava esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o erro está sendo causado pelo comentário logo após a abertura da tag do PHP.
Tente remover o comentário e colocar o comando `namespace` logo após o `<?php`.

Comment: Você testou? Teoricamente não afeta mesmo, mas é o que o erro diz (a declaração da namespace deve ser o primeiro item do script).

Comment: Sim eu testei tirando o comentário e o erro continuou.

Answer (score -1):

Alguns casos que eu já peguei era apenas espaço no começo do arquivo exemplo.

[image: Repare no começo do arquivo tem um espaço.]

Ao retirar este espaço no começo do arquivo antes da tag de abetura do php o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score -3):

Se você precisa identificar e remover arquivos que contenham o caractere "BOM" (Byte Order Mark), você pode utilizar os seguintes comandos:

1. Encontrar arquivos com "BOM":

```bash
grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' /seu/diretorio
```

Este comando usa o `grep` para procurar recursivamente (`-r`) por arquivos que contenham o "BOM" no diretório especificado. O caractere "BOM" é representado pelos bytes hexadecimais `EF BB BF`.

2. Remover o "BOM" de arquivos encontrados:

```bash
find /seu/diretorio -type f -exec sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' {} \;
```

Aqui, `find` é usado para localizar todos os arquivos (`-type f`) no diretório especificado. O comando `sed` é então utilizado para editar (`-i`) cada arquivo, removendo o "BOM" da primeira linha (`1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//`).

Esses comandos podem ser úteis ao lidar com arquivos que possuem o caractere "BOM" e você deseja identificá-los ou removê-los.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).